# Получить данные из адресной строки

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно получить данные из адресной строки. К примеру после обращения к серверу я получаю данные в виде: `http://test.com/bapi.html#id=100` и мне нужно получить значение id. Как это реализовать?

Comment: JS: `+window.location.hash.split('=')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
    String answer = "http://test.com/bapi.html#id=100";
    String id= answer.substring(answer.indexOf("="));
```

Или так:

```
    String answer = "http://test.com/bapi.html#id=100";
    String correct = answer.split("=")[1];
```